# Show/hide tabs from right to the left

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, hide, show

Good night! I have tabs.

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
$(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
 $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
 $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```css
.wrapper .active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but they show with "fadeIn" and hide with "fadeOut". i want to make they show from the right (in animate.css it's class "fadeInRightBig") and hide to the left(in animate.css it's class "fadeOunLeftBig"). Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

http://codepen.io/Himechi90/pen/LpjReE

```
<div class="tab_content">
    <div class="tab_item animated fadeOutLeftBig">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div class="tab_item animated fadeOutLeftBig">Содержимое 2</div>
    <div class="tab_item animated fadeOutLeftBig">Содержимое 3</div>
</div>

$(".tab_item").addClass("fadeOutLeftBig").hide("fast").eq($(this).index()).switchClass("fadeOutLeftBig", "fadeInRightBig").fadeIn("fast")
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```